how to fire only last event listener
I am faced with a problem related to a number of identical event listeners. The main problem is that these events are executed in the order they were added: first in, first out. How can I change this order so that events are executed in reverse order: first in, last out? I know about capture property and it helps but not quite good.
Let's say first of all i open message top bar:
const MessageTopBar = ({
    onClose,
    title,
    mainIconSlot,
    closeIconSlot,
    description,
    preventClose
}: MessageTopBarProps) => {
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleClose = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            !preventClose && event.key === 'Escape' && onClose();
        }

        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleClose);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleClose)
        };
    }, [])

    return (
        // jsx
    );
};

It's our first listener. Now i open details component:
const OutletDetails = ({
    onClose,
    name,
    description,
    type,
    info,
    shouldCloseOnClickOutside = true
}: {
    description?: string;
    info?: React.ReactNode;
    name: string;
    type: FeedTypes;
    onClose: () => void;
    shouldCloseOnClickOutside?: boolean;
}) => {

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!containerRef.current) return;

        const handleClick = ({ target }: MouseEvent) => {
            target instanceof Node && !containerRef.current?.contains(target) && onClose();
        };

        const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            event.key === 'Escape' && onClose();
        };

        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
        shouldCloseOnClickOutside && document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
       // jsx
    );
};

It's our second listener. Now open modal:
export const ModalProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    // another code here

    const handleEscapeDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        !isAsyncActionLoading && event.key === 'Escape' && closeModal();
    };


    const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        
        const keyListeners = {
            Tab: handleTabDown,
            Escape: handleEscapeDown,
        };

        keyListeners[event.key as keyof typeof keyListeners]?.(event);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!modals.length || !bodyRef.current) return;

        bodyRef.current.focus();

        document.body.style.paddingRight = window.innerWidth - document.body.offsetWidth + 'px';
        document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden');

        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true);

        return () => {
            document.body.classList.remove('overflow-hidden');
            document.body.style.paddingRight = '0';
        
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true);
        };
    }, [isAsyncActionLoading, modals, handleKeyDown]);

    return (
       // jsx
    );
};

This is our third event listener. Because we used useCapture as true, the modal will close first, the message top bar second just because this event was added earlier than the details. How can I change this order? If I use useCapture as true for every listener, it will close the message top bar first, even if the modal open.

So after a while i came up with global provider for DOM events:
export const DomEventsProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const [listeners, setListeners] = React.useState(new Map());

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!listeners.size) return;

        const entries = [...new Map([...listeners]).entries()];

        const mappedListeners = entries.map(([type, listeners]) => {
            const lastListener = [...listeners.values()].pop();

            if (!lastListener) return { type, listener: () => {} };

            document.addEventListener(type, lastListener, true);

            return { type, listener: lastListener };
        })

        return () => {
            mappedListeners.forEach(({ type, listener }) => {
                document.removeEventListener(type, listener, true);
            })
        }

    }, [listeners]);

    const addEventListener = React.useCallback(<E extends keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap>(type: E, listener: (event: GlobalEventHandlersEventMap[E]) => void) => {
        setListeners((prevState) => {
            const listeners = new Map([...prevState]);

            listeners.has(type) ? listeners.set(type, new Set([...listeners.get(type)!, listener])) : listeners.set(type, new Set([listener]));

            return listeners;
        });

        return () => {
            setListeners((prevState) => {
                const listeners = new Map([...prevState]);

                listeners.get(type)?.delete(listener);
                !listeners.get(type)?.size && listeners.delete(type);

                return listeners;
            })
        }
    }, []);

    const removeEventListener = React.useCallback(<E extends keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap>(type: E, listener: (event: GlobalEventHandlersEventMap[E]) => void) => {
        setListeners((prevState) => {
            const listeners = new Map([...prevState]);

            listeners.get(type)?.delete(listener);
            !listeners.get(type)?.size && listeners.delete(type);

            return listeners;
        })
    }, []);
    
    const value = React.useMemo(() => ({ addEventListener, removeEventListener }), []);

    return (
        <DomEventsContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </DomEventsContext.Provider>
    )
};

I added clean up function inside addEventListener just for better DX. So now we can use like this:
const OutletDetails = ({
    onClose,
    name,
    description,
    type,
    info,
    shouldCloseOnClickOutside = true
}: {
    description?: string;
    info?: React.ReactNode;
    name: string;
    type: FeedTypes;
    onClose: () => void;
    shouldCloseOnClickOutside?: boolean;
}) => {
    const { addEventListener } = useDomEvents();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!containerRef.current) return;

        const removeEventListener = addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            event.key === 'Escape' && onClose();
        });

        return () => {
            removeEventListener();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
      // jsx
    );
};

